# How to get list of printers on mac using .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, xamarin.mac, mac-catalyst

I am working on a desktop only .NET MAUI application that targets both Mac and Windows. I need to create Printing Service to communicate with the installed printers on the machine. On Windows i was able to achieve that using `System.Drawing.Printing` using `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` property. However I've been strugling to do it on Mac. Since `AppKit` namespace is not available on Mac, I can't use `NSPrinter.PrinterNames` property to do so. I need to use low-level objective c messaging to create and use objects at runtime.

I have been following [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprinter) and tried the following:

```
        [DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
        public static extern IntPtr IntPtr_objc_msgSend(IntPtr receiver, IntPtr selector);

        [DllImport("/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib", EntryPoint = "objc_getClass")]
        public static extern IntPtr objc_getClass(string className);

                IntPtr clsNSPrinter = objc_getClass("NSPrinter");
                IntPtr selPrinterNames = ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle("printerNames");
                IntPtr printerNamesPtr = IntPtr_objc_msgSend(clsNSPrinter, selPrinterNames);
                var printersNSArray = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSArray>(printerNamesPtr);
                var printerNames = NSArray.StringArrayFromHandle(printersNSArray.Handle);
                return printerNames.ToList()
```

After sending the `"printerNames"` message to `NSPrinter` class and converting the `Ptr` to `Object`, I got empty list. I have tried sample application using Xamarin.Mac where it has support to `AppKit` and I've used `NSPrinter.PrinterNames` and it returns list od four printers, exactly the ones i have installed on the machine.

I have also tried to send `"alloc"` selector to `NSPrinter` first and then the selector `"printerNames"` but that way i got an exception that said: `"Unrecognized selector printerNames when sent to class"`